# python working with classes adding joining removing items

Tags: python, class, superclass, python-3.6

doing this for a homework, don't understand how this would work, so explaination with steps will help lot.
The question is hard understand so have not been able to understand and try.
Here is the question,divided into 3 parts.
You are given the following superclass. Do not modify this.

```
class Container(object):
    """ Holds hashable objects. Objects may occur 0 or more times """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Creates a new container with no objects in it. I.e., any object 
            occurs 0 times in self. """
        self.vals = {}
    def insert(self, e):
        """ assumes e is hashable
            Increases the number times e occurs in self by 1. """
        try:
            self.vals[e] += 1
        except:
            self.vals[e] = 1
    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for i in sorted(self.vals.keys()):
            if self.vals[i] != 0:
                s += str(i)+":"+str(self.vals[i])+"\n"
        return s
```

Write a class that implements the specifications below. Do not override any methods of Container.

```
class Bag(Container):
    def remove(self, e):
        """ assumes e is hashable
            If e occurs one or more times in self, reduces the number of 
            times it occurs in self by 1. Otherwise does nothing. """
        # write code here
def count(self, e):
    """ assumes e is hashable
        Returns the number of times e occurs in self. """
    # write code here
```

• For example, d1 = Bag()

```
d1.insert(4)
d1.insert(4)
print(d1)
d1.remove(2)
print(d1)
prints 4:2
4:2
```

• For example, d1 = Bag()

```
d1.insert(4)
d1.insert(4)
d1.insert(4)
print(d1.count(2))
print(d1.count(4))
prints 0
3
```

Second part:

Write a method in Bag such that if b1 and b2 were bags then b1+b2 gives a new bag representing the union of the two bags.

• For example, a = Bag()

```
a.insert(4)
a.insert(3)
b = Bag()
b.insert(4)
print(a+b)
prints 3:1
4:2
```

third part:

Write a class that implements the specifications below. Do not override any methods of Container.

```
class ASet(Container):
    def remove(self, e):
        """assumes e is hashable
           removes e from self"""
        # write code here
def is_in(self, e):
    """assumes e is hashable
       returns True if e has been inserted in self and
       not subsequently removed, and False otherwise."""
    # write code here
```

• For example, d1 = ASet()

```
d1.insert(4)
d1.insert(4)

d1.remove(2)
print(d1)

d1.remove(4)
print(d1)
prints 4:2 # from d1.remove(2) print

    # (empty) from d1.remove(4) print
• For example, d1 = ASet()
d1.insert(4)
print(d1.is_in(4))
d1.insert(5)
print(d1.is_in(5))
d1.remove(5)
print(d1.is_in(5))
prints True
True
False
```

Thank you.

Comment: Correct your indentation.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for your professor or TA - you're basically just dumping an entire problem set here. If you can narrow it down to something specific and show at least an attempt at solving this, then it might be on topic. Otherwise, this is way too broad.

Comment: did you got the third part correct?

Comment: My question was long because I did not understand the question ask itself. I worked my own answer by understanding this don't know how to post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a subclass, the first thing you need to do is understand the class you want to subclass. So, the first thing you need to do is understand what `Container` does.

It has two magic methods, `__init__` and `__str__`, and one ordinary method, `insert`. Explore `insert` first by doing this:

```
d1 = Container()
d1.insert(4)
print(d1)
d1.insert(2)
print(d1)
d1.insert(4)
print(d1)
```

You get this output:

```
4:1

2:1
4:1

2:1
4:2
```

There are 3 sets of responses, one from each `print()` call. Can you see what is happening? When you insert `4`, you see `4:1`. If you insert `4` a second time, then you see `4:2`. In other words, the string representation you are seeing is *value*`:`*count*.

This works because `Container` has the member `vals` which is a dictionary. Each item in the dictionary is *value*`:`*count*, just like in the string representation.

Your first task is to write a subclass `Bag` that does everything that `Container` does, but also has the methods `remove` and `count`.

The method `count` just produces the same answer for one value in `Container` that `__str__` produces for all values. Choose the corresponding value out of the dictionary and return the number of occurrences. Note that it is okay to ask for the count of a value that isn't there: return `0` in that case.

```
class Bag(Container):
    def count(self, e):
        return self.vals.get(e,0)
```

Check that this works:

```
d1 = Bag()
d1.insert(4)
d1.insert(4)
print(d1.count(4))
```

The other half of this bit is to write `remove` which is the opposite of `insert`. What does `insert` do? If the value you are inserting is already in `vals`, it increases the count, otherwise it sets the count to 1. So `remove` needs to decrease the count, and if it goes to zero, removes the item from the dictionary. Note that it is okay to try and remove a value that isn't there: just ignore it in that case.

```
    def remove(self, e):
        if e not in self.vals:
            return
        self.vals[e] -= 1
        if self.vals[e] < 1:
            del(self.vals[e])
```

Be careful when adding this bit of code. The indentation needs to line up with `count`.

Now that you have the basics, your next task is to write an `__add__` method that adds two bags together. In other words given `Bag`s `a` and `b`, you need to combine `a.vals` and `b.vals`. Start with a copy of `a` and then add the contents of `b` to it. You already have a method do to the adding: use the method `insert`.

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        result = self.__class__()
        result.vals.update(self.vals)
        for value,count in other.vals.items():
            for _ in range(count):
                result.insert(value)
        return result
```

Be careful when adding this bit of code. The indentation needs to line up with `count`.

The third part of your question is really a repeat of the first part. The `remove` method is the same. The `is_in` method is the same as `count`, except that it returns `True` or `False` instead of a number.

Comment: In python 3, you can just use `__class__()` instead of `self.__class__()`

Comment: can you give exact code for the is_in method?

Comment: Not even prepared to try, eh? `return e in self.vals`

Comment: Thank you BoarGules
Really detailed and the type of answer that help.

Comment: also,there's one place where the third part fails, perhaps my remove is fault?
            d1.insert(4)
            d1.insert(4)
            d1.insert(4)
            d1.remove(4)
            print(d1.is_in(4))

Comment: Did you actually write the `remove` method of the `ASet` class?